# PHP script dies after reaching some output limit

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a Wordpress website with a background process started with an admin `POST`. Everything worked fine, until for some reasons the process started to show a strange behaviour:

1. php-fpm does not log anymore to my usual `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`. The only way to log something is to catch the workers output to the main php-fpm `error.log`.
2. the process dies with no error, exceptions, or messages whatsoever. It just stops logging and it does not go to completion.
3. Commenting off `error_log` instruction increases the lifetime, putting them back decreases it. It's like there is some kind of output limit.
4. It is horribly consistent: the point of death is predictable. The procedure is a batch processing of an array, and the last item logged is always the same, for each configuration of `error_log` instructions.

I've tried to max all possible related limits I can think about:

```
php_admin_value[post_max_size] = 64M
php_admin_value[output_buffering] = off
php_admin_value[upload_max_filesize] = 64M
php_admin_value[max_input_vars] = 30000
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 30000
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 512M
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

plus in `wp-config.php`:

```
set_time_limit(0);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
ini_set("error_reporting", "E_ALL");
ini_set("log_errors", "on");
```

Nothing changes (even if `phpinfo()` shows the correct values).

Is my php-fpm possessed? What variable can determine a silent kill on x bytes outputted?

Memory, swap and disk space are okay.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn’t with the input array? If it fails at the exact same point in the array *every time*, then that’s the most likely reason. It looks like it’s encountering something that it can’t handle and dies.

Comment: Not every time! if, say, I log ```n``` lines per item processed it dies at the ```m-th``` item, if I log ```2n``` lines per item it dies sooner (or later with ```n/2``` lines).

Comment: When you said the last item logged is always the same, I presumed it was the same array item. In that case it looks more processing-related alright... I've no great insights on that though, but so good luck with it! :)